# ASP.NET BasePage dataset type is not defined

Tags: .net, asp.net, dataset

I'm am creating an ASP.NET 2.0 web application that uses a BasePage.aspx that is inherited by all other .aspx pages.  I have designed a dataset with 3 stored procedures in it called dsBaseInfo.  I declare it as a private member of the class and when I go to run the application it tells me the dsBaseInfo type is not defined.  I also tried just a Dataset instead of my dsBaseInfo and I get the same error, type not defined.  I have tried Private dsBase as dsBaseInfo, Private dsBase as dsBaseInfo = nothing, Private dsBase as new dsBaseInfo, Private dsBase as Dataset, and so on.  I even tried moving declaration to the PreInit sub and same error.  I have also done the Private dsBAse as dsBaseInfo in a .aspx that inherits the BasePage and it works on that page.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class BasePage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private dsBase As dsBaseInfo = Nothing    'dataset
    Private _userInfo As UserInfo

    Private Sub Page_PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
        If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            _userInfo = New UserInfo

            If dsBase Is Nothing Then
                If Session("BaseInfo") Is Nothing Then
                    dsBase = New dsBaseInfo
                    RetrieveBaseInfo(dsBase)

                    Session("BaseInfo") = dsBase
                Else
                    dsBase = TryCast(Session("BaseInfo"), dsBaseInfo)
                End If
            End If

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub RetrieveBaseInfo(ByVal dsBase As dsBaseInfo)
        Using da As New dsBaseInfoTableAdapters.ssp_GetUserBaseInfoTableAdapter
            da.Fill(dsBase.ssp_GetUserBaseInfo, User.Identity.Name)
        End Using

        Dim intID As Integer = dsBase.ssp_GetUserBaseInfo.Rows(0)(dsBase.ssp_GetUserBaseInfo.IDColumn.ColumnName)

        Using da As New dsBaseInfoTableAdapters.ssp_GetCompaniesTableAdapter
            da.Fill(dsBase.ssp_GetCompanies, intID)
        End Using

        Using da As New dsBaseInfoTableAdapters.ssp_GetMasterMenuListTableAdapter
            da.Fill(dsBase.ssp_GetMasterMenuList, intID)
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do both pages include `Imports System.Data` at the top of the file?  (I don't see it in the supplied code.)  `DataSet` is in that namespace, so you'll need to import that namespace in order to reference the class without fully-qualifying it.

Comment: System.Data is in the References of the Project.

Comment: @langc334: I was going to ask about that if this didn't work as well, so that's good.  But there's a difference between the project references and the imported namespace.  Those three `Imports` lines at the top are key in this case.  All they're essentially doing is telling that file (and _only_ that file) what implicit namespaces to reference for classes.  As it stands right now, to use `DataSet` in that file it would need to be declared as `System.Data.DataSet`.  If you add `Imports System.Data` to the top of the file, you should be able to reference it directly as `DataSet`.

Comment: Thanks David, just threw me off that the file inheriting basepage didn't need the imports statements, but the basepage did.